# How to avoid reminder when adding an event to the calendar

Tags: android, android-calendar

I add an event to the calendar with this method:

```
private void writeToCalendar() {
   Intent l_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
   l_intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
   l_intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "title");
   l_intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "");  // description
   l_intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, ""); //eventLocation
   l_intent.putExtra(Events.DTSTART, System.currentTimeMillis());  // beginTime
   l_intent.putExtra(Events.DTEND, System.currentTimeMillis() + EVENT_LENGTH);  // endTime
   l_intent.putExtra(Events.ALL_DAY, 0);  // allDay
   l_intent.putExtra(Events.STATUS, Events.STATUS_CONFIRMED);  // eventStatus
   l_intent.putExtra("visibility", 0);  // visibility
   l_intent.putExtra("transparency", 1);  
   l_intent.putExtra(Events.HAS_ALARM, 0);  // hasAlarms
   l_intent.putExtra(Events.ALLOWED_REMINDERS, "");  //allowedReminders
   try {
       startActivity(l_intent);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), getResources().getText(R.string.calendar_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

Unfortunately the event that is proposed to the user to be added gets automatically an alarm (reminder) set on 10 minutes (at least this happens on my phone). As you can see I tried to set to "" the allowed reminders and to set to 0 the "hasAlarms" flag. Still, when adding the event it automatically proposes to the user to set a reminder at 10 minutes. The user can delete the reminder before saving the event, but this is not what I want, I would like it to miss the reminder by default, as soon as for my application a reminder does not really make sense.
Can someone explain how to avoid this?

Thank you.